# Offline files / Directory sync

Tags: mac, network

I have a MacBook Pro that I travel with a lot.  I also have a NAS for my home network.  Many timesI use my MacBook in areas where I do not have Internet access.  I'd like to have copies of some of my folders while I travel and sync up when I return back home.  Is there anything like the Microsoft 'Offline Files' feature present in the MacOS, or do I need to script something like this myself?

Comment: Have you ever tried Dropbox? Just throwing it out there; always a possibility... and I know it keeps local copies and syncs when you have internet.

Answer (score 1):

I use [chronosync](http://www.econtechnologies.com/pages/cs/chrono_overview.html) to sync my laptop back to my iMac and NAS. It's not a free solution, but once its setup it works. There are other options available from a simple rsync script to other sync tools.

Answer (score 0):

[SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/)'s sync feature actually works very well. It also encrypt's everything on your machine, so plain data never gets transmitted. I use this for important files I like to keep sync'ed. I do agree though, that Dropbox works very well. I have also been a ChronoSync user for a couple of years, and it's sync features are great as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you roll your own (I did), I would strongly suggest you use Unison.  I have a couple of launchd jobs that watch key directories (~/Documents, ~/.dotfiles).